# No recibo valores de SELECT FROM pero si de INSERT INTO y si existe el registro (MVC,PDO,MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, pdo, select

hola estoy trabajado con PHP y MySql con PDO y el modelo vista controlador (MVC) pero tengo un error al tratar de hacer un SELECT * del lado del modelo mi intriga es que funciona cuando hago INSERT INTO y cuando es un SELECT siemple lo que yo hago es una validacion de existencia de un registro en la BD y le aplico rowCount() para saber si la trajo exitosamente y la igual a 1 pero siempre llega 0 pero el registro si existe en la base de datos

```
$datosUs=[
            "clave_usuario"=>$usuario,
            "contrasenia"=>$contrasenia
        ];

        $datosCuenta=loginModelo::iniciar_sesion_modelo($datosUs);


        if($datosCuenta->rowCount()==1){
            $row = $datosCuenta->fetchAll();
```

y esto lo manda al modelo

```
protected function iniciar_sesion_modelo($datos){
        $sql=mainModel::conectarBD()->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE clave_usuario='RIVE' AND contraseña='123456' AND estatus=true");

        $sql->bindParam(":clave",$datos['clave_usuario']);
        $sql->bindParam(":contrasenia",$datos['contrasenia']);

        $sql->execute();

        return $sql;
    }
```

mi funcion PDO que llama el modelo

```
protected function conectarBD(){

        $cadenaconexion = new PDO(SGBD,USER,PASS);

        return $cadenaconexion;
    }
```

**

--------------ARRIBA NO ME TRAE UN VALOR |

--------------ABAJO SI ME TRAE VALORES  |

**

> en mi consulta siemple no uso el bindParam simeple mente le doy un valor asignando variables

```
$buscar_servicio=mainModel::consultas_simples("SELECT * FROM servicios WHERE clave_servicio='$clave_servicio'");
```

> mainModel

```
**protected function conectarBD(){

        $cadenaconexion = new PDO(SGBD,USER,PASS);

        return $cadenaconexion;
    }
    //ejecucion de consultas simples para agilizar codigo
    protected function consultas_simples($consulta){
        $respuesta = self::conectarBD()->prepare($consulta);
        $respuesta->execute();

        return $respuesta;
    }
```

> cuando hago un insert

```
$guardar=servicioModelo::agregar_servicio_modelo($datos);

            if($guardar->rowCount()>=1){

                $alerta=[
                "Alerta"=>"limpiar",
                "Titulo"=>"¡Listo!",
                "Texto"=>"El servicio se ah agreagado con exito.",
                "Tipo"=>"success" 
            ];
            return mainModel::sweet_alert($alerta);
            }else{

                $alerta=[
                "Alerta"=>"simple",
                "Titulo"=>"Atención",
                "Texto"=>"No se pudo agregar el servicio./nIntentelo nuevamente.",
                "Tipo"=>"error" 
            ];
            return mainModel::sweet_alert($alerta);
            }
```

> modelo

```
protected function agregar_servicio_modelo($datos){
        $sql=mainModel::conectarBD()->prepare("INSERT INTO servicios(clave_servicio,servicio,descripcion) VALUES(:clave,:servicio,:descripcion)");

        $sql->bindParam(":clave",$datos['clave_servicio']);
        $sql->bindParam(":servicio",$datos['servicio']);
        $sql->bindParam(":descripcion",$datos['descripcion']);

        $sql->execute();

        return $sql;
    }
```

Comment: Arriba no te trae valores porque la consulta falla. Si no hay marcadores en la consulta no puedes usar `bindParam` y tampoco en ese caso deberías usar `prepare / execute` sino  `query`.  Si haces esto simplemente debería funcionar: **`$sql=mainModel::conectarBD()->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE clave_usuario='RIVE' AND contraseña='123456' AND estatus=true"); return $sql;`** O sea, `query` es para consultas donde no hay marcadores que deben ser sustituidos por variables, a fin de evitar inyecciones SQL. En consultas con todos sus datos no necesitas `prepare`.

Comment: muchas gracias, si me confundi en la consulta es que lo estaba tratando de emviar con valores con defecto para ver si asi funcionaba y por que con parametros no pero hice mal mi publicacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arriba no te trae valores porque la consulta falla. Si no hay marcadores en la consulta no puedes usar bindParam y tampoco en ese caso deberías usar `prepare` / `execute` sino `query`.

Si escribes tu código de arriba así, debería funcionar:

```
protected function iniciar_sesion_modelo($datos){
        $sql=mainModel::conectarBD()->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE clave_usuario='RIVE' AND contraseña='123456' AND estatus=true");
        return $sql;
    }
```

En cuanto a la otra consulta, debes aplicar adecuadamente el criterio de consultas preparadas, que es muy simple.

Por ejemplo, puedes pasar dos parámetros a `consultas_simples`, uno sería la consulta a preparar, y el otro los datos:

```
/*
    *Nótese que ahora la función recibe otro parámetro 
    *llamado $arrParams, el cual servirá para pasar los datos
    *y enviarlos al manejador a través del método execute
*/
protected function consultas_simples($consulta,$arrParams){
    $respuesta = self::conectarBD()->prepare($consulta);
    $respuesta->execute($arrParams); //PDO permite pasar los valores en el execute y esto es magnífico
    return $respuesta;
}
```

Para llamarla, harías esto:

```
$strSQL="SELECT * FROM servicios WHERE clave_servicio=?";
$arrParams=array($clave_servicio);
$buscar_servicio=mainModel::consultas_simples($strSQL,$arrParams);
```

Lo que hemos hecho ha sido:

- Poner un marcador de posición en la consulta `?`
- Pasar en `$arrParams` los valores y en la función aprovechamos la ventaja de que PDO nos permite pasar los parámetros que eventualmente se pasarían en `bindParam`, como un array en el `execute`.

Supongamos que quieres enviar una consulta preparada a `consultas_simples` con más parámetros:

```
$strSQL="SELECT * FROM servicios WHERE clave_servicio=? AND nombre=? WHERE id>?";
$arrParams=array($clave_servicio,$nombre,$id);
$buscar_servicio=mainModel::consultas_simples($strSQL,$arrParams);
```

El truco es escribir bien tu consulta, con  sus marcadores, los que necesites, y poner en el array cada valor correspondiente a los valores de cada marcador. Le pasas los datos a `consultas_simples` y PDO hace el resto.

Espero te sirva y si hay dudas, lo puedes manifestar en comentarios.

Comment: muchas gracias me ayudaste a comprender mejor el PDO al final de cuentas mi error no solo era la consulta si no tabien la Ñ en contraseÑA en mi sentencia sql